# Unity 2d Android Failed to Build for no reason

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, 2d

[image]

Three days ago, i didn't encounter any errors, just scripting, build it, test it, all work normally, but now i've update my projects i cannot build it, why? It didn't tell me what's the error, i'm so confused, i've check all my script not a single error exist, i have tried re-open unity, restart my pc, even re-install the whole Unity, it still not won't build, but when i change the platform to PC, it can build, and a blank project, it works, it only happen to my current project,,, HELP!

Comment: What you have changed through out the days you mentioned.. any idea ? and show us the whole error not just a simple screenshoot.

Comment: @sujoybyte Well, some UI, Coin Spawner, and Add More Background, that's it,,,, How to show the whole error? I don't know how, sorry

Comment: One way you can share your editor log, that is present in the three dot menu of your console window (for example https://github.com/JetBrains/resharper-unity/issues/391) or at least the part of the log after the build error is written

Comment: @sujoybyte I tried crazy things, so i copy MyProject for testing to MyProject02, and open in Unity, tried to delete 2 files and then try to build it, untill all MyAsset are empty! it still won't build! Omg, so the problem is inside the Packages folder, but i can't figure which one,,,, so for the editor Log, do i need to copy all of them? it's so much

Answer (score 1):

It's solved. It's the Universal RP! I removed it and then delete the folder:

`C:\Unity Projects\MyProject\Library\Bee\Android\Prj\Mono2x\Gradle\launcher\build\intermediates\desugar_graph\release\out`

and then delete the CurrentProject folder before building the project!

Comment: Always use some kind of source control system like git (github) even if you only want it locally, so you can understand what change caused a certain error or issue.